# $.ajax can't find server side url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to using servers and ajax so I might add useless information or forget  important information, let me know if either is the case.

I have a `main.js` and `test.js`. From my main.js I use express to get a folder to the client side, in this folder are my `.html` and `.css` files. For some more clearance, it looks like this:

```
/main.js
/test.js
/clientSide/index.html
/clientSide/style.css
```

Now from the `.html` file I'm trying to run the `test.js`, thats on the server side. I've tried to do this with jquery as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./test.js",
  success: function (result) { alert("succes"); },
  error: function (result) { alert("no succes"); }
})
```

I've also tried `url: "../test.js"` in case the url would take the `.html` as the root. Sadly both give a **404 error** saying there is no `test.js` file. 

Is someone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `url: "/test.js"`, Also what should `test.js` returns as a response?

Comment: Doesn't make sense *posting* to a JS file which is a static resource. Also to go back one directory need `"../test.js"`

Comment: @charlietfl maybe he is working on a node server

Comment: @Wael I've tried that as welk, but sadly doesn't workshop either. test.js should update a sqlite3 database, its response to the client should only be of this was succesfull of nog.

Comment: @Abdeslem yes, I'm indeed working with a node server.

Comment: Please share `main.js` and `test.js` content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow access to the file. Using Express, you can make a path static using:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Everything inside the public folder can now be accessed. In your case, create a public folder and include your test.js file.

**Edit**

> This is indeed what I've done tot make my clientSide folder public.
>   But test.js should be on the serverside since it should update a
>   sqlite3 database there

In this case, you should create an API. With Express, this will be very simple. Simply create a route:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  //perform functions here
  //send response
  res.send(data);
});
```

In your jquery code, you can call the route like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/test',
  success: function (result) { alert("succes"); },
  error: function (result) { alert("no succes"); }
});
```

You can read more about routing in Express here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: This is indeed what I've done tot make my clientSide folder public. But test.js should be on the serverside since it should update a sqlite3 database there.

Comment: Then instead of accessing the file directly, you should create an API. With Express, create a route that performs all of the functions found inside test.js

Comment: Can you tell me how I go about doing that, or do you maybe have a link explaining it further for me? I can't seem to find much when googling.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example on how to retrieve data correctly using ajax. If you backend server file is test.js, you can replace the url data with that. In the example that I implemented, am getting data on smoke.php server side using ajax. This method will work for you

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

         $(document).ready(function(){


         //$('#result').click(function(){

         var post1 = 'data to post if any';





        $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('Please Wait. Data is being Loaded');


         // assuming that you want query result by posting a variable
         var datasend = "alert1="+ post1;

         $.ajax({

         type:'POST',
         url:'smoke1.php',
         data:datasend,
         crossDomain: true,
         cache:false,
         success:function(msg){
         alert('success');
         $('#loader').hide();
         $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);
         }

         });

         //})

         });


    </script>


<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body></html>
```

**smoke.php**

```
<?php

$smoke_status            = 'I am not smoking';
echo htmlspecialchars($smoke);
?>
```